# Build a translator using python. I don't know why translation = translation + "G"

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pycharm

```
def translate(phrase):
 translation = ""
 for letter in phrase:
      if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
           if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "G"
           else:
                translation = translation + "g"
      else:
           translation = translation + letter
 return translation
```

I dont undertand why translation = translation + "G".Can someone help me

Comment: Can you please format your code? See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `translation = translation + "G"` adds 'G' to the existing string `translation`

Eg. if `translation = "Hi"`
then `translation = translation + "G"` comes out to be "Hi"+"G" which is "HiG"

All that I can tell is what this code in words. If you could tell me what you wanted the output to be I could have helped you more.

So what the code does is that it takes a phrase/sentence and it replaces all vowels with a g (Capital G if vowel is capital or small g if vowel is small).

Eg. phrase="Welcome to Overflow"

Output -> translation="Wglcgmg tg Gvgrflgw"

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it. Now I understand.